# Как преобразовать String в int с проверкой на ошибку?

Tags: java

Как не допустить ошибки если введенная String не может быть преобразована в int.

```
while(true)
{
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s = buffer.readLine();
    if (s.equals("exit"))
        break;
    int i = Integer.parseInt(s);// здесь потенциальная ошибка.
}
```

Comment: https://younglinux.info/java/exception#:~:text=%D0%92%20Java%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81,%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2.

Answer (score 8):

Конечно же ловить и обрабатывать исключение

```
int i;
try {
 i = Integer.parseInt(s);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
 i = -1;
}
```

Comment: Позвольте спросить, отлавливание ошибок является нормальной практикой в программировании или это, такой себе, узаконенный костыль, который стоит применять только в крайнем случаи?

Comment: @СергійСитюк Не ошибок, а исключений. Да, абсолютно нормальной. Есть две модели программирования: 1) при ошибках мы бросаем исключение, 2) при ошибках мы возвращаем специальный результат и код ошибки

Answer (score 1):

Смотря чего вы ожидаете от строки, если можете предположить что строка на входе будет состоять не только из цифр тогда обычно перед парсингом убирается мусор из строки, например все символы кроме цифр

```
  String s = ".123r";
  int i;
  try {
   i = Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   i = -1;
  }
```

**Работает только для положительных чисел**

Или `.replaceAll("[^\\d\\-]+", "")` - заменяет все кроме цифр и `-` работает если минус стоит перед цифрой

Если спарсить не удалось - получим `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Вот не нужно додумывать за пользователя и пытаться угадать, что же он хотел ввести. А если пользователь ввел `0x10` в надежде на то, что программа распарсит ввод как hex значение. А мы без предупреждения отбросили все не цифры и получили вместо 16 - 10. Если в программу поступило неожидаемое значение, то это как раз и есть **исключительная** ситуация. И как ее обрабатывать программа не имеет представления

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, насчет додумывать согласен, а вот про hex значение вопрос - если попытаться Integer.parseInt("0x10") то пользователь получит NumberFormatException разве нет? Для этого же существует Integer.decode("0x10")

Comment: Он получит **уведомление** о том, что программа не в состоянии проанализировать его ввод. А это гораздо лучше, чем отбросить `x` и получить ошибочное значение уже в программе

Comment: То, что вы предлагаете хорошо работает для фильтрации ввода. Когда программа не дает ввести ошибочные символы, а пользователь зразу видит что он вводит